# conda commands throw error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda.core'

Tags: anaconda, conda

All conda commands throw an error. How can I debug this, especially without being able to run any conda commands?

I've google a lot and have not found any approach to tackling this sort of problem. The "similar" questions here aren't similar enough to provide any insight for my specific case.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
    module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_list.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..core.prefix_data import PrefixData
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda.core'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 150, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1371, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1126, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1137, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1207, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda.core'
```

Comment: what did you type to get these messages?

Comment: "conda list" and "conda info" are two commands that throw that error.